# Linux terminal editor with image background support

Tags: linux

I like to have a background image in my terminal. I used several before but switched to my 2 colour scheme ( white background, black text colour ) back because I couldn't read the stuff so good. Is there some terminal/plugin, what ever there is as possibility which adjust the text colour so one still can read it properly with whatever background image one chooses?

Edit: This is a really radical example but I mean something like this

[image]

It has to adjust the text colour in contrast to the background image.

Comment: Is there any terminal that does *not* support this? The question is rather *how* to accomplish it – but that question should better be asked at e.g. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/search?q=[bash]+color+answers%3A1) (link goes to the corresponding answers – [even closer hits here](https://superuser.com/search?q=[bash]+text+color+answers%3A1) – best hit: [how to change the color of the terminal](https://superuser.com/q/84416/143340) ;)

Comment: With your edit: I doubt that will be possible – unless you play with opaqueness (to "dim" the background, making it "paler"). Text color won't change automatically in the middle of the line just because there's a different background; a terminal app is usually not considered a "playground", but a "working place".

Comment: @Izzy but why not make work a little bit more pleasant :)

Comment: Sure. But if it's *too pleasant*, it's no longer work :) I'm afraid the only solution is chosing a "less colorful" background image and adjust opacity. [rxvt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rxvt) might be a good choice then as terminal: *Newer versions of rxvt have primitive support for pseudo-transparency.* The "background image" would be your desktop then :)